# Rails: Uninitialized constant 'Product::CSV'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following Product class which is raising an `uninitialized constant Product::CSV` exception.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150*150>" }

  def self.import(file)  
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|  
      product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new  
      product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)  
      product.save!  
    end  
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 65):

You need to require the CSV library.

```
require 'csv'

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 40):

I did the same mistake today. For those who have the same problem, I would like to share this.

Please make sure that you *require csv* library in *config/application.rb*.

#### config/application.rb

```
require 'csv'
```

#### Resources

- [RailsCasts #362-exporting-csv-and-excel](https://github.com/railscasts/362-exporting-csv-and-excel/blob/master/store-after/config/application.rb)
- [GoRails #45 Exporting Records To
  CSV](https://gorails.com/episodes/export-to-csv)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar bug where, for a while, I could use class methods on CSV with no problem. Then, all of a sudden, I was getting uninitialized constant errors. I realized that many Ruby gems use `multi_xml` or something similar as a dependency gem, and as a side affect that gem initializes the CSV class when your server starts. If you remove the gem that required this, you will start getting exceptions wherever you've been relying on this side effect. You can patch it by writing `require 'csv'` in each file, but using `multi_xml` gem or something similar is probably the easiest solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to a constant under a namespace, say Class or Module, by default Ruby think this constant name is under namespace.

In your case, when you mention `CSV` inside `Product` class, Ruby will look for a `Product::CSV` constant. That's desired action.

Of course you don't want that because your `CSV` module is at top namespace. In this case you must explicitly express this by adding `::` before the name.

```
::CSV.foreach #.....
```

Comment: It's `::CSV`, not `::csv`.